# Ajax Toolkit, asynchronous javascript return values to a global variable

Tags: visualforce, javascript, api, ajax, ajax-toolkit

I am creating this Visual force page that will heavily rely on the Ajax tool kit and trying to do it asynchronous style, because I think that is what the cool kids are doing.

Is it not possible to return a value from the "success" function to a global variable "result" ? right now it is return undefined.

Here is a snippet of what I am trying to do:

```
var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstance Where Id IN (SELECT ProcessInstanceId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem)", {
  onSuccess : success,
  onFailure : failure
});

function success(result) {
  var records = result.getArray("records");
  var result2 = new Array();

  var recLength = records.length
  for (var i=0; i<recLength; i++) {
     result2.push(records[i].TargetObjectId);
  }
  return result2;
}

document.write(result);
```

Any thoughts, should I just do it the synchronous way?

Comment: why not use javascript remoting instead of ajax toolkit as you are using a visualforce

Comment: Because that involves writing apex code, and what I am doing right now would be more of prototyping. Also, there is a small chance that this won't be within a VF page.

Answer (score 2):

To do it asynchronously, simply assign `result2` to `result`. The result (no pun intended) is that the reference to `result` will resolve to `window.result`, the global variable. It should be noted that `document.write(result)` wouldn't work in any case, unless the callback beats the parser (which it won't). You won't be able to use your exact design, as you'd have to use something like `innerHTML` or another construct to get the results directly into the page. This is related to the fact that you'd have to call `document.open` first, which would clobber the page.